# How to keep a good pace, and keep people drawn in

Tags: online-roleplaying, attendance

I am managing an online roleplay, and I am basically the do all. I've written and update lore, I narrate action and sequences, and I manage the Discord Server that we use. I also have a small team of consultants who help me with ideas and managing.

Anyways, we are in our second arc, and I've noticed a major difference from the first one. The first arc had 13 episodes or sessions, and those episodes would last about 5 to 6 hours. It was enjoyable, re-reading it. But now, we're 13 episodes in, but it's a bit different. Thanks to school, we only roleplay about 3 hours, and roleplay two days in a row, have a break for a day and resume. I think this schedule is hurting us, as people don't join as often, and there's just less detail.

(Added from Original) Our schedule is we roleplay two days in a row then we take a day-long break, before repeating. Currently, have 8 roleplayers, but it's online, so we have different time zones. For example, I and my Admin live in Florida, we're real-life friends, so this how we collaborate and work together for the roleplay. But we have people in Arizona, Tennesee, England, and the Netherlands, which makes it difficult to keep people in, whose time would be like 3 AM for them when it's 6 PM for us. Usually, I have a general idea of what the roleplay will focus on, but, a lot of the time, it will skew to what my roleplayers do, which is fine. Recently, our schedule allowed us to roleplay on Friday and Saturday, which was excellent, as I myself am a teen, and so are most of my roleplayers. Meaning we can roleplay for so long, before we have to go to bed, for school. These recent roleplays stretched a lot longer, and in doing so, I got more roleplaying out my group. And, while I do allow people to join, we had only six people for the first arc, and now that one of the roleplayers has invited people, it's getting hard to get them introduced, while focusing on the people who made the roleplay even possible. I don't want to slow down so much, as to drag on my OG team, but not go so fast, that the new ones don't have time to get adjusted.

I and my team are thinking of having roleplay once or twice a week instead, but I would appreciate some more help. And I guess what I am asking is, how can I, with the given circumstances, keep a refreshing pace, so that I have a good turnout, and people are interested. Me and my admin we're thinking of, instead of the two-day roleplay, one day break, repeat schedule, instead, we roleplay once or twice a week, on set days, and the rest of the week is free for side roleplay, but no main roleplay, if that makes any sense.

Comment: There are many ways to structure online roleplaying and advice for one doesn’t necessarily work for another setup. This question is a bit vague about your setup and schedule, which may impair your ability to get advice. For example, it doesn’t tell us whether it’s a fixed set of players (how many?) or an open, anyone-welcome group. There are more details like that which could be clearer. Could you [edit] to explain more about how your game works?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've updated it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I don't think there's a single best answer to this sort of question. It depends a lot on your particular players, their attention spans, their work load, and so forth.

That said, I think you can find a solution by **continuing to experiment**. Try different schedules until you find one that works well for your group.